# Binomialcdf answer verification

Tags: probability

An urn contains 6 red balls and 14 yellow balls.  5 balls are randomly drawn with replacement.  What's the probability exactly 4 red balls are drawn?

$$5\, _nC_r\, 4 \cdot (4/20)^4 \cdot (4/5)^1 = .0064$$

Is my answer correct?

Comment: No it is not correct.

Comment: ${5\choose4}(\frac{6}{20})^4(\frac{14}{20})$